# How to invoke a predicate functor based on a variable instead of a name

Tags: prolog

Let's say I've declared predicates `a` and `c` as follows:

```
a(b).

c(D, E) :- D(E).
```

I'd like to believe that `c(a, b)` succeeds, as `D(E)` matches `a(b)` if `D` is bound to `a` and `E` is bound to `b`, but (in SWI Prolog anyway) syntax checking is looking for an operator following `D` in the definition of `c`, so apparently there's a rule that unification binds variables only to arguments, not functors. Is there some trick for asking the question posed by `c`, in which the identity of a predicate is one of the unknowns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`call/2`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2)
to call a predicate with the given name and parameters. So your `c/2` predicate is equivalent to `call/2`:

```
c(D, E) :-
    call(D, E).
```